# Каков алгоритм создания сайта,

Tags: php, css

В процессе изучения Html и CSS хочу создать сайт. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каков алгоритм его создания? Знаю, что надо установить Apache. А дальше что? Устанавливать PHP? Объясните вкратце, чтоб хотя бы представление иметь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В дополнение к «классике» (Apache, MySQL, PHP) напишу ещё один вариант организации сайта (сразу предупрежу, что он сложнее Apache+mod_php):

- в качестве основного сервера вместо Apache — [nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/) (иногда [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)), коротый почти ничего не умеет, зато очень быстро отдаёт css-файлы, картинки и прочую статику;
- за nginx прячется какой-нибудь сервер, на котором вертятся скрипты (тот же Wordperss, например): в случае PHP это может быть какой-нибудь FactCGI-сервер или [fcgiwrap](https://github.com/gnosek/fcgiwrap), в случае Ruby — [Unicorn](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn), в случае Python — [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) или [GUnicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) и т.д.;
- в качестве базы данных для сайта можно взять [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) (а некоторые простые сайты зачем-то даже извращаются с [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/));
- работу спрятанных за nginx серверов может контролировать какой-нибудь [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) (хотя непосредственно разработки сайта это уже не касается).

Если цель — просто создать какую-то домашнюю страничку без всякой динамики, то будет достаточно одного лишь nginx — он прекрасно будет отдавать html-странички.

Если цель — вести свой личный блог, то, как советовали ранее, можно поглядеть в сторону Wordpress (тогда нужно настраивать что-нибудь для работы PHP), однако есть ещё такая вещь — генератор статических сайтов, который из текстовых файликов с постами (написанными, например, в формате Markdown, необязательно HTML) генерирует готовые html-странички, картинки и стили, которые сможет раздавать всё тот же nginx. Лично я использую [Pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/).

Если цель — разработать какой-то полноценный динамический сайт с преферансом и дамами (коллективный блог, интернет-магазин, онлайн-игра, убийца фейсбука, клон stackoverflow и т.п.) или же если хочется попрактиковаться в программировании, то здесь может идти речь как о более продвинутой CMS вместо Wordpress (их очень много хороших и разных), так и о собственной разработке на каком-либо языке программирования. Здесь нужно отметить важные вещи:

- на PHP свет клином не сошёлся. Сайты можно разрабатывать почти на любом языке программирования; популярностью пользуются, например, Ruby ([Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)) или Python ([Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/));
- стоит почитать про [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), который позволит избежать множества проблем и который используется в большинстве фреймворках (помимо указанных ранее Rails и Django есть ещё MVC-фреймворк [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) на «классическом» PHP);
- далеко не каждый хостинг это всё поддерживает: на большинстве вертится обычный Apache с PHP. Если делать сайт на чём-то другом, то, возможно, придётся разбираться в линуксе и брать [VPS (VDS)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPS) или выделенный сервер.

Если цель — разобраться, что вообще представляет из себя веб и как это всё работает, то на Apache+PHP в таком случае зацикливаться не стоит, советую погуглить и почитать материал понемножку по всему вышеперечисленному.

P.S. Всё вышеописанное в целом касается развёртывания серьёзных сайтов уже на продакшене; если хочется просто потыкать вот прям щас на локальном компьютере, то по запросу «windows simple http server» гуглится много интересных мелких программок (название той, которую сам использовал, к сожалению, забыл), но выпускать их на продакшен нельзя. Ну и XAMPP ещё есть как нечто среднее.

Answer (score 5):

Что вопрос, что ответы, никак не учитывают весовые коэффициенты предпринимаемых действий. И в итоге до боли напоминают одну [старую байку](http://phpfaq.ru/hyperboles#artist).
К примеру, один из отвечателей настрочил пространный ответ, который вызывает только одну ассоциацию, с анекдотом про "Папа, ты с кем сейчас разговаривал".

В общем, каждый тетерев поёт про свою осину, и совершенно не учитывает ни контекст вопроса, ни уровень автора.

Думаю, надо автору объяснить, что никакого "алгоритма" создания сайта в принципе не существует. Есть несколько подходов, один из которых, (как раз требующий установку локальных РНР и Апача), требует **предварительного многолетнего обучения.** и редко когда делается силами одного человека.

И что установка любых программ на *домашнем* компьютере не приведёт к появлению сайта в интернете.

В общем, в зависимости от того, что мог иметь ввиду автор

1. Чтобы буквально "создать сайт", неделю поизучав Html и CSS, прямая дорога на http://www.ucoz.ru/ Это как раз то что нужно - сайт, который уже есть в интернете. Для текущего уровня - отличный выбор, все с этого начинали.
2. Если, наигравшись с укозом, автор вырастет из его рамок, и сможет финансово потянуть расходы примерно в сумме $1/мес., можно будет говорить о покупке **готового хостинга** (т.е. уже настроенных Апача и РНР), и установке **готовой программы** для создания сайтов - CMS, например Wordpress.
3. Если речь идет об **инструкции** по установке на домашний компьютер локального веб-сервера, то, во-первых, эта задача не имеет смысла без п.4, а во-вторых, задавать специальный вопрос на Stack Overflow для этого не нужно - в сети полно пошаговых инструкций.
4. Если хочется изучать программирование вообще и веб-программирование в частности, то следует понимать, что к "созданию сайтов" это имеет довольно опосредованное отношение. Хороший программист обычно работает над одним и тем же сайтом, постоянно улучшая его.

Резюмируя:

- Если хочется разместить в интернете фото любимой дочурки и её первый лепет, но при этом не устраивает формат социальных сетей - то ucoz.
- Если начальница велела разместить сайт фирмы в интернете - заряжаешь бюджет побольше и обращаешься в какую-либо веб-студию.
- Если хочешь учиться созданию сайтов вообще - покупаешь книжки, устанавливаешь локальный сервер и запасаешься терпением - первый сайт, который будет не стыдно показать людям, у тебя получится еще очень и очень не скоро.

Comment: Да, про то, что автору может хватить укоза, и про начальницу я как-то не подумал. Но вообще по своей практике могу сказать, что написание и поднятие своего приемлемого сайта на php в принципе возможно за месяцок-другой без предварительного обучения (с копипастом из гугла и соответствующим качеством кода, но всё же).

Answer (score 2):

`HTML`, `CSS`, `javascript` можно играться вообще ничего не устанавливая.

`PHP` да, нужна дополнительная поддержка.

http://open-server.ru/ платформа, установив которую, вам будет доступен локальный сервер с уже установленным окружением (PHP, базы данных и тд), которого будет достаточно для дальнейшего обучения.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

а) Если задача детально изучить все технологии веб-разработки, попробуйте установить локально XAMPP получите уже рабочие MySQL + PHP + Perl. Напишите движок (CMS) на PHP. Далее уже настраиваете сервер на публичную работу.

б) Приобретите хостинг с поддежкой php, mysql. Установите Wordpress - будет почти готовый рабочий сайт.